# Why do I have a malformed calendar error from golang-ical?

Tags: go, icalendar

I try to parse the content of an ICS file, for this I use the library [golang-ical](https://github.com/arran4/golang-ical)

the error appears here :

```
cal, err := ics.ParseCalendar(reader)
```

and got this error

```
error parsing calendar malformed calendar; expected begin or end
```

I've take the file from [here](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/jours-feries-en-france/) and also passed it to an ICS validator online and everything is fine with it

The file come from the front-end and is receivied via a route and look like this

```
func functionClosingCalendarsImportIcsPreview(req *http.Request, resp *ClosingCalendarsResponse) (errors api.Errors) {
        cal, err := ics.ParseCalendar(req.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error parsing calendar", err)
        }
        fmt.Println("cal", cal)
    }
```

I've also tried to read the file directly from my computer like this

```
data, err := os.ReadFile("~/T1316/jours_feries_metropole.ics")
    reader := strings.NewReader(string(data))
    cal, err := ics.ParseCalendar(reader)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error parsing calendar", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("cal", cal)
```

both methods aren't working and I can't find much documentation about ICS file in golang

Comment: Print req.Body to see what exactly is sent to you.

Comment: I've tried this and transform it in a string, it give me an readable result but the ParseCalendar function expect an io.reader parameter. So I've tried to transform back my string into an Reader but still, the error malformatted calendar occur

Comment: Also I haven't found another library that golang-ical, so my main concern is how to parse ICS data.